# Just curious of best way to make this Java program

Tags: java

I'm still learning java but the program I want to make is a number selector based on my own rules. Simply put, you have 1-10 and you pick a number based on the number you choose decides what other numbers you have to pick from.

For example, the numbers will be 1-10. if I select 1, it'll show other numbers I can select (2,5,7,8), then after selecting another one it'll limit my numbers down to 5, 7 (removing 8 because i selected 2).

I was just wondering if there was any better way to do this besides a bunch of if/else statements with all the numbers I can select if I choose 1. Making an array of all possible numbers would probably be good, but what about for the numbers removed since those are more random?

Comment: How does selecting `1` from the set `(1, 2, 3, ..., 10)` generate the set `(2, 5, 7, 8)` ?

Comment: Sounds like homework. Can you post what you have tried? Can you only use arrays? What are the requirements for the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement. It will provide you choose different options without using `if` statements and it is more clear.

For example, if you have a `number` variable (and in the case that you enter the number by `Scanner`):

```
int number = scanner.nextInt();
```

And you have a `switch` statement like this:

```
switch (number) {
            case 1:  
                     System.out.println("You choose option 1");
                     //Code when the user input it's 1
                     break;
            case 2:  
                     System.out.println("You choose option 2");
                     //Code when the user input it's 2
                     break;
            case 3: 
                     System.out.println("You choose option 3");
                     //Code when the user input it's 3
                     break;
            case 4:  
                     System.out.println("You choose option 4");
                     //Code when the user input it's 4
                     break;
            case 5:  
                     System.out.println("You choose option 5");
                     //Code when the user input it's 5
                     break;
}
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you? (granted this is pseudo code)

```
Set original = //Fill with {1,2,...10}
Set selectedSoFar = new HashSet();
while(original.isEmpty() ==false){
    int selectedNow = selectOne(original)
    selectedSoFar.add(selectedNow)
    original.remove(selectedNow)
}
private int selectOne (Set selection ){
    int selected = -1
    while (!selection.contains(selected)){
    // Print the selection.
    //Ask the user to type one of the number
    //assign it to "selected"
    }
    return selected
}
```

Obviously, you can fill in remaining code for populating the original set as well as somehow reading  the selection in "selectOne"
Hope this helps!

------- Update -------

Sorry, I am used to Scala's immutable collections, so I had to change my original answer to suite Java.